# ActionScript. Can't get data from local xls file

Tags: excel, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, as3xls

I want to get data from xls file with help of as3xls.

```
private var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
private var sheet:Sheet;
private var loadedFile:ByteArray;

private function sendLogistImport():void {  
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
    file.browse();
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, 
        function (e:Event):void { 
            loadedFile = e.currentTarget.data as ByteArray;
            var excelFile:ExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
            excelFile.loadFromByteArray(loadedFile);                
            sheet = excelFile.sheets[0]; 
            Alert.show(sheet.getCell(1,0).value);
        }
    );
}
private function onFileSelect(e:Event):void {
    file.load(); 
}
```

But I get this error at the **excelFile.loadFromByteArray(loadedFile);**:

```
Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/readUTFBytes()
    at com.as3xls.xls::ExcelFile/boundsheet()[/Users/manuelwudka-robles/Documents/Flex Builder 3/as3xls/com/as3xls/xls/ExcelFile.as:633]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::call()
    at com.as3xls.xls::ExcelFile/loadFromByteArray()[/Users/manuelwudka-robles/Documents/Flex Builder 3/as3xls/com/as3xls/xls/ExcelFile.as:309]
    at Function/<anonymous>()[D:\logist.as:244]
```

This is my xls file's screenshot :

[image]

Here is my xls file:
http://www.filedropper.com/template_1

Please tell me, where is my mistake?

Comment: This is not a `.xls` file, it's a screenshot. Anyways, the error is pretty clear about what's happening, the code is trying to read towards the end of the file, so the options here are that it's a bug in the library, that your files structure is not supported (the library was last updated nearly 6 years ago), or that your files structure is incorrect.

Comment: I think everything is ok with my xls file. I created it in old Excel 2003 format. I added link above in main text to xls file, so you can look at him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it with various XLS formats, and it can't read any of them. Judging from [the comments](https://code.google.com/p/as3xls/wiki/Tutorial), the support for the various XLS formats is rather bad.

Try it with different XLS formats, maybe you find one that works, other than that I'm afraid I can't help you, fixing the problem in the library is a monstrous task, and I wouldn't touch it with a ten-foot pole: http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf

Also check out some of the forks around the net, like for example https://github.com/djw/as3xls, they may have some fixes implemented that get you going.

And if nothing work for you, then I'd suggest to look for another library, and/or even use a totally different file format (like CSV) if that is an option.

Comment: Could you please suggest me another library working with XLS formats? Using CSV format would be difficult for users.

Comment: @zigfridus If I knew of any I would have mentioned them, sorry, but check my updated answer, I've included a link to a fork which might work for you (can't test it right now).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try this library and then I'll inform you here about results.

Comment: This library [link](https://github.com/djw/as3xls) works with my code and xls file correctly. Thank you very much!